# Saving files does not work for me, the 1st and only parameter of the json file does not change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't understand why saving files doesn't work for me. The Json file should contain 1 line, it is there, but the key value does not change.
I looked on sites and all had code similar to mine.
What do I need to do to fix this problem.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public int countSave;
}

public class SaveData : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string path;
    Data data;

    private void Start()
    {
        data = new Data();
        data.countSave = UI.count;

        path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/save_data.json";
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) Save();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) Load();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        string jsonSave = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
        File.WriteAllText(path, jsonSave);

        Debug.Log("Save file created at: " + path);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
            string jsonLoad = File.ReadAllText(path);
            data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data>(jsonLoad);

            Debug.Log("Load data complete: current count = " + data.countSave);
        }
        else
            Debug.Log("There is no save files to load!");
    }
}
```

Here is the part of the code that updates the count value

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class UI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI text = new TextMeshProUGUI();
    public static int count;

    private void Update()
    {
        text.text = count.ToString();
    }

    public void CountButton()
    {
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: The key object that should change is countSave. And it changes due to another code, where its value increases by 1 when you press the button

Comment: where are you updating UI.count?

Comment: I would say saving and loading probably works fine. Updating `countSave` is what is broken and we can't see that code.

Comment: I added a piece of code that updates the count value

Comment: The `Start` function is called once. That is the only place where `UI.count` is referenced. After that you can change `count` as much as you want but the `Data` class knows nothing about that.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is such a stupid mistake. Thanks again! Everything is working!